# Access Rental Database: Preventig an equipment to be used in two different projects

Tags: ms-access

I'm looking for a way to make a database for equipment managment but I don't know how to go forward from my point.

I have now 3 core tables to do this part, the EQUIPMENT table, where I have a list of all the equipment I have (with the different units on record and everything),

besides this one I have the PROJECT table, where I have all the information of the rental service and I also have a PROJECT_DETAILS where I place the equipment for the given project

Examples:

EQUIPMENT TABLE: Brand,Model,Internal Number: 
[Ford;Transit; 1][Ford;Transit;2][Ford;Transit;3][Mercedes;Sprinter;1][Mercedes;Sprinter;2] Etc...

PROJECT TABLE: Project code, Start, End, Client Name:
[XX001;2016/08/05;2016/08/10;Steve][XX002;2016/08/06;2016/08/8;Bill] etc...

PROJECT DETAILS: Project Code, Equipment, Internal Number:
[XX001;Transit;1][XX001;Transit;2][XX002;Transit;3][XX002;Sprinter;1]

So what I want to do is when trying to make a new project, I want the equipment to dissapear from its combo box if the equipment is in use in another project

Answer (score 1):

I would continue to flesh out the database schema with the following additional tables:

- `RENTAL:`   This represents "the rental contract itself." The rental might be active, or it might be being contemplated. Perhaps, all `RENTAL`s belong to (one) `PROJECT` ...
- `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT:`   This one-to-many table lists the items that *are to be rented* when this rental contract goes into effect.
- `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT-RESERVED-NOW:`   This is “where the rubber hits the road.” This table contains an entry for every piece of `EQUIPMENT` that is "right now, irrevocably, 'off the lot.'" It is related both to `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT` *(to justify the presence of the record),* and directly to `EQUIPMENT` *("where's that dump truck and why is it not here on the lot? Oh. We rented it. I see...")*.  I'd probably insert a record into the table when the equipment went out the door, and remove the record when the equipment was returned. The *presence* of a row in this table ... only one row per `equipment_id` is allowed ... is sufficient to indicate that a piece of equipment is reserved or off-the-lot, and why.

In this view of things, `PROJECT`s, from time to time, "rent things," or *"plan to* rent things in the future." *(Nobody rents anything unless it is associated with a project, say...)* Each `RENTAL` consists of a list of equipment to be rented. Then, when stuff goes off-the-lot and we need to be able to *quickly(!)* account for it (without poring through a bunch of `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT` and `RENTAL` records in a very-laborious query ...), the `RESERVED-NOW` table gives us an immediate answer.

---

You should also familiarize yourself with the concept of `TRANSACTIONs`, which Access fully supports. A "transaction" is an *atomic* group of SQL statements that will be "all or nothing." For instance, when you start to process the departure of a piece of equipment from the lot, you "start a transaction."  Then, you perform the SQL statements needed to insert into `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT-RESERVED-NOW` and to update `RENTAL-EQUIPMENT` records and so-on ... then, you "`COMMIT` the transaction."  All of the changes that you made, all at once, *then* "become permanent."

What? *"Oopsie! Something went wrong!!"* No problem: just `ROLLBACK` the transaction instead, and you're right back where you started. Nothing that you did during the transaction 'actually happened.' (Rollbacks often appear in `on error goto...` blocks.)

Finally, also look at things like "foreign keys" and "referential integrity."

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work.  Basically depending on on how your project is set up, you would want to look at anything where the end date is past your current client trying to schedule "schedule_date" let's say and before or equal to the schedule_date.  This way if they select a date range, anything that is between those dates wouldn't show up.

```
SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE internal_number NOT IN (SELECT internal_number FROM project INNER JOIN project_details ON product_details.project_code = project.project_code WHERE end_date >= schedule_date and begin_date <= schedule_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way I read your question, it sounds like ProjectDetails is recording the combinations of the project and the equipment.  It also sounds like you aren't interested in keeping a historical of those assignments, and are therefore removing them from projectdetails when they are no longer assigned.

So (again, if I understand correctly), what you want to do is to show all of the records in the equipment table that does not exist in the projectdetails table - correct?

```
SELECT * FROM equipment INNER JOIN projectdetails ON equipment.equipid = projectdetails.equipid
```

Answer (score -1):

I broadly concur with DHW and Mike Robinson - From my reading of your structure you are using the project details table as a junction table to relate the equipment and the projects. Comparison of this table to the equipment should give  a list of all unused equipment.

I had a go on an access database at my end and I joined the Equipment Table to the Project Details Table and did a left join so that ALL equipment was shown. I then added the Equipment field of the Project Details table. In order for this to work you need a relationship between the Project Details Table and the Equipment table and you must ensure the Project Details Equipment Field and the Equipment Table Internal Number are same data type ie Long Integer. I then ensured then put a filter on the Project Details.Equipment field criteria set to Null. The SQL I used for this was

```
SELECT EquipmentTable.InternalNumber, EquipmentTable.Brand,EquipmentTable.Model, ProjectDetails.Equipment FROM EquipmentTable LEFT JOIN ProjectDetails ON EquipmentTable.InternalNumber = ProjectDetails.Equipment WHERE (((ProjectDetails.Equipment) Is Null));
```